# PHP mail() function: Cannot used outside data from database

Tags: php, database, sendmail

I'm trying to send email using PHP mail() function and I got problem when trying to call the recipient name (from the database) in the email message.
The code goes here:

```
class User{
   function callname(){
     $user = $_SESSION['id'];
     $query = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id='$user'"); // trying
     while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){            // to call
         return($result['username']);}}}                  // "username" in database

$user = new User;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
  $check = mysqli_stmt_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'"));

  if ($check==TRUE){
    $name = $user->callname(); // call the function
    $to = "myemail@domain.com";
    $subject = "Example Subject";
    $headers = "From: My Example Email"."\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $message = "Hai $name, this is the new message.";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
} else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Sorry, username not exist !");
</script>
<?php }}
```

Everything goes fine, the email was sent successful, the headers were good, but the message was not. `$name` not call the username. So the message only like this:

```
Hai , this is the new message.
```

Please help. Any answer will really helpful. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**
Do you mean like this? (I've changed to `mysqli`)

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id='$user'");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row=$resulr->fetch_array()){
   return $row['username'];

   if($$mysqli->num_rows($result) == 0){
      return $row['usern'];
   }
```

If its right, the result still same. The username didn't print in the email.
    }

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: yeah, I'm in proccess to migrate man. Thanks for remind.

Comment: I've edited the code. Is that right?

Comment: Using `mysqli` is better. You still aren't running the query. You need to use `mysqli_query($query)` because `mysqli_fetch_array()` doesn't accept a String, it accepts a `mysql_result` object.

Comment: Also, MySQLi is not connected in the code

Comment: I see you've updated some things. I'll assume you'll fix the syntax errors (`$$`, `$resulr->fetch_array()`) and address your logic issue - if there are zero rows returned, you still return the username. Try changing that case to "[no name]" or something for debug purposes. The goal here is to figure out whether your query is working - returning 0 rows means you might need to fix the SQL itself.

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) takes the type of object that `mysql_query()` returns. You need to do this:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id='$user'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
// ...
```

You should also be using `mysqli` in an object-oriented fashion, but that is an issue for another post.

Comment: Yup, I've updated to mysqli. Your code still not work man. The message still resulting same content. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It can be helpful to print `$result` before your return then, and maybe add an if statement to handle the case of no results for the user (`if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)`) and also print something there to help debug what's going on.

Comment: please see my update code. Do you mean like that? Thanks a lot for your help. +1.

Answer (score -1):

First off you shouldn't be using `mysql` because it is depreciated try using `mysqli`, second off you need to get the result from a `mysql_query`

Code should be this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id='$user'");
```